# Getting URL for specific tile on XYZ layer?

Tags: qgis-3, xyz-tiles

I am using custom XYZ tiles layer served from a local server. It works great most of the time, but some of the tiles appear to be missing or damaged (show up as white squares).

Is there a way to figure out what are X/Y/Z numbers for a specific tile visible on the screen so I can go to that URL and investigate what is wrong with the file?

I am using QGIS 3.6.2 on Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For such cases, it is much easier to debug in a browser. You can create a web map with your tile layer and view it in a browser such as Chrome. When you open Developer Tools, you can see the failed requests in the Network tab.

I have created a simple leaflet based template using JSFiddle. You can open [https://jsfiddle.net/spatialthoughts/6mz4obtw/1/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdbF7.png) and replace the tileUrl with your own URL and click Run. Open More Tools --> Developer Tools --> Network and browse the map on the bottom-right panel. The failed requests would show up there.

[image: jsfiddle demo]

Comment: That's what I end up doing -- write small a leaflet.js wrapper and then right click on a tile.